# Calling Global function from Python Script in C++

Tags: python, c++

I have a Pyhton Script "PythonScript.py" and a global function declared as:

```
def runSimulation(filename = ''):
```

`runSimulation` gives output as an object from class `Simulation`.

To access runSimulation, I am using following code in C++:

```
PyObject *pName = PyString_FromString("PythonScript.py");
PyObject *pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
PyObject *pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);
PyObject *pFunction = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, "runSimulation");
PyObject *pResult = PyObject_CallFunctionObjArgs(pFunction, NULL);
Simulation *pSimulation = boost::python::extract<Simulation *>(pResult);
```

However, I am getting "segmentation violation while running it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using just `boost::python`. You could import your file, and get the function quite easily.

Comment: I see now that pModule does not exist. I have tried full path of Script also as argument to PyString_FromString. What am I doing wrong that PythonScript.py is not being imported?